# For a function $f:\Bbb R^n→\Bbb R$, Differential $f(x)$ is a linear function. But why?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, real-numbers, conformal-geometry

I just read that for a function $f: \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R$, the differential  $df_x$ is a linear function for every $x\in\Bbb R^n$. I can't convince myself why that's the case. In particular, I don't understand what $\Bbb R^n → \Bbb R$ has to do with it.

Comment: What's your definition of $df_x$?

Comment: I think it should be differential of f(x)

Comment: Yeah, but how do you define the differential? As the answers say, it being a linear function should hold by definition.

Answer (score 1):

That's the definition of the differential, so I'm unsure why any convincing is needed. The differential $\mathrm d_xf$ of a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is defined as the unique linear map $\mathrm d_xf:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-\mathrm d_xf(h)}{\Vert h\Vert}=0.$$

The reason why it makes sense to *define* it that way is that the differential is the generalization of the derivative in one dimension, which is essentially a linear approximation of the function: The function is approximately $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+f'(x)\cdot h$. And a linear approximation of a higher dimensional function is then $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+\mathrm d_xf(h)$. The above equation is just a formal definition of what $\approx$ means.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$, $df_x$ is by definition the linear map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-df_x(h)\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0$. This does not absolutely mean that, for a differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$, the map $$d f_\bullet:\Bbb R^n\to\{\text{linear maps }\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m\}\\ x\mapsto df_x$$ is linear. In fact, it hardly ever is: in short, you shouldn't expect $df_{\lambda x+\mu y}=\lambda df_x+\mu df_y$.

However, for each $x$ the map $$\{\text{differentiable functions at }x\}\to\{\text{linear functions }\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m\}\\ f\mapsto df_x$$ is linear: in other words, $d(\lambda f+\mu g)_x=\lambda df_x+\mu dg_x$.

Comment: Do you think that in my question above ℝ^→ℝ means  ℝ^→ℝ^1 and if so, is this a special case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "What does $R^n\to R$ have to do with it?
"!  That is telling you what the setting of the question is! If n= 1 we have the standard "Calculus 1" problem of differentiating a function of single real number to the real numbers such as "$f(x)= e^x$".  Its derivatve is, of course, $f'(x)= e^x$ and its "differential" is $df= e^x dx$.  At a specific x= a, $df= e^a dx$, which we can think of as the linear operation "multiply dx by the **number**, $e^a$. If n= 2, f is a real valued function of two variables such as $f(x,y)= x^2+ y^2$.  Its "derivative" is the gradient, $\nabla f= 2x\vec{i}+ 2y\vec{j}$ and it "differential" is $2x dx+ 2y dy= (2x\vec{i}+ 2y\vec{j})\cdot (dx\vec{i}+ dy\vec{j})$.  That is, the differehtial is the **linear** operation of "multiplication by $2x\vec{i}+ 2y\vec{j}$.